# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error. Command '/usr/bin/python' not found

Tags: ios, python-3.x, selenium-webdriver, macos-monterey

Facing issue with running iOS tests (Java, Webdriver, Appium) on macOS Monterey 12.3.
This version has Python3 instead of Python2. usr/bin/python3 is present, but WebDriver is looking for usr/bin/python.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Command '/usr/bin/python' not found. Is it installed?

I installed python2 -- didn't help.
Does anybody know how to fix it or know workarounds?

Java client for Appium Mobile Webdriver version 8.0.0

Comment: "python2"...  you installed a legacy unsupported version of python ?

Comment: Yes, but -- any Python you are installing can't be installed into system /usr/bin directory.

Comment: yes it can,  right here:   https://www.python.org/